# How to provide password directly to the sudo su -<someuser> in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

I got a requirement to automate in shell script for `sudo su -<someuser>` which asks for password.

How to provide password directly to the sudo su - in shell scripting for IBM AIX servers.
I have tried using
`echo <password> | sudo su -<someuser>` it did not work. kindly help on this.

Answer (score 7):

Use `-S`

`man sudo`:

> -S, --stdin
>   Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the standard input instead of
>   using the terminal device.  The password must be followed by a newline character.

so you can use:

`echo <myPassword> | sudo -S su <someuser>`

**Edit:** This above did not work on a testing Ubuntu. It seems like the second command "su " is to fast after prompting password query.

I did a workaround to wait a second so the echoed password could be filled in, and then second sudo should be able, to run `sudo su - foobar`:

```
echo "password" | sudo -S sleep 1 && sudo su - foobar
```

Comment: In my Debian `su` exits. However `sudo su -` invoked just after works thanks to cached credentials. It may be a workaround if you can rely on this behavior.

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: @raamsaara: what did exactly not work? did you get an error? 
meanwhile I edited my answer to add a workaround, which worked on my machine.

Comment: Works great with Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!

Comment: What do you do on systems that don't have `sudo`, and only have `su`?

Answer (score 3):

With [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). A *stub* command may be like this:

```
expect -c '
 log_user 0
 spawn /usr/bin/sudo su - someuser
 expect "*: "
 send "thepassword\n"
 interact
'
```

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1343270/432690) to a similar question.

---

Another approach is with `sudo -A`.

1. Create a file, say `pass`.
2. Make the file accessible only to you: `chmod go-rwx pass`.
3. Make it executable to you: `chmod u+x pass`
4. Edit the file and make it a script that prints your password:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   printf '%s\n' 'yourpassword'
   ```
5. Now you can do this:

   ```
   SUDO_ASKPASS="./pass" sudo -A su - someuser
   ```

Note: in this case you provide password for `sudo` (not for `su`); use the one `sudo` wants.

Comment: Thanks . But where can i incorporate the <someuser>

Comment: @raamsaara In `su` syntax. Answer improved.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the `:NOPASSWD` option of sudo so you don't need a password. Like:
`%wheel ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD: ALL` in /etc/sudoers