# How to run a sudo command with task spooler?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

When I try to run a task  with task spooler that requires sudo access like

```
ts sudo echo "hello world"
```

it doesn't ask for my password and exits with error 1

Alternatively, I have some tasks that may require my password during execution. How can I interact with it?

Answer (score 1):

What `ts` runs is not connected to a terminal. I assume you don't want to set up `sudo` to work without password. Then you need to provide your password without a terminal. This can be done with `sudo -A`:

From [`man 8 sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html):

> `-A`
> Normally, if `sudo` requires a password, it will read it from the user's terminal. If the `-A` (askpass) option is specified, a (possibly graphical) helper program is executed to read the user's password and output the password to the standard output. If the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable is set, it specifies the path to the helper program. […]

Write a helper script. The script should just print your password. An example script is in [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1351876/432690).

Then you can do this:

```
SUDO_ASKPASS="/path/to/helper/script" sudo whatever
```

With `ts` the right syntax is:

```
SUDO_ASKPASS="/path/to/helper/script" ts sudo whatever
```

It's up to you how the script knows the password. The password may be hardcoded (like in the example), stored in a file (the script would then just `cat file`), obtained by connecting to some agent or interactively from you (e.g. by displaying a GUI window; read [How do I ask password by GUI prompt while using sudo in script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254072/108618)).

Securing the script (and the file, if any) is your concern now.

Note [`sudo` may be configured not to work without a terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122616/108618).