# Execute a command in new interactive tcsh shell

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, tcsh

How can I execute a pre-command in a new tcsh interactive shell?

Ex: For mimicking `bash -O globstar` in tcsh we can do `set globstar`.

However, I need to start a new `tcsh` shell with 'set globstar' without depending on / changing the user's `rcfile`.

`tcsh -c 'set globstar` won't work as it won't leave the interactive shell. Exits immediately after executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

Bash understands `--rcfile`, which allows you to source alternative `.bashrc`, but I haven't found similar option for `tcsh`.

Without it, I managed to achieve what you want by modifying [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1343270/432690). It uses [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

log_user 0
spawn /bin/tcsh
send "set globstar\n"
interact
```

Adjust paths if needed. Save the code in a file, make the file executable, then run it.

Comment: I was wondering if `tcsh` has some sort of inbuilt support for it.
Thank you for pointing out `expect` @kamil-maciorowski.