# Bash Script That Inputs Strings Into a Command After Executing it

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script

I want to make a script (in bash language) that allows me to automatically log in to service X. Service X will ask for my username and password, and I want my script to input them. Here's the code:

```
Service X
#input username
#input password
```

Here is what I have to do manually:

```
root@loacalhost~$ Service X  
Service X: Username:  
Service X: Password:  
You have successfully logged in to service X.  
root@loacalhost~$
```

Here's what I want it to do:

```
root@loacalhost~$ ./script.sh
You have successfully logged in to service X.
root@loacalhost~$
```

How can I do this? I looked at redirection, STDIN, STDOUT, etc, but I wasn't really able to understand how to do this? I also looked at using 
 `echo` to do it, but no luck either.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague, your Service X is a mystery, we know nothing about it.

Usually tools that read credentials from the terminal don't use stdin for this. The service may or may not use stdin. It may provide an option to read credentials from stdin. It may provide an option to read credentials from a file.

Note: from now on I will use `servicex` as the command because `X` in your `Service X` is an operand, so with options it should weirdly look like `Service -a -b --optionc X`. I doubt such syntax was your intention.

If `servicex` reads credentials from stdin by default, this should work:

```
printf '%s\n' "your username" "your password" | servicex
```

If it reads credentials from stdin only when told to do so, something like:

```
printf '%s\n' "your username" "your password" | servicex --credentials-from-stdin
```

In both cases it may be better to read credentials from a file that no other user can read:

```
<secret_file servicex --credentials-from-stdin
```

Or the service may provide an option to read credentials from a file (leaving stdin for another purpose or unused):

```
servicex --credentials-from-file secret_file
```

But most likely the service uses the terminal device directly to ask for credentials and to read them. In this case [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) is the right tool. Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1351876/432690) or [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1343270/432690). A vague sketch of a solution to your vague problem may be:

```
expect -c '
 log_user 0
 spawn servicex
 expect "Service X: Username:"
 send "your username\n"
 expect "Service X: Password:"
 send "your password\n"
 interact
'
```