# Su Into New Environment and Run Command from New User As Alias

Tags: linux, bash, shell, su

I would like to run a `su - <desired_user>` but then also execute a command. I want to become that user in the new shell but just source a specific file.

The `desired_user` above is a batch user, shared across many regular users, and therefore nothing will work if put in the `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, etc.

For example, it would be combining the `su` and sourcing command into one alias that I can run.

```
(user1) $ whoami
user1
(user1) $ su - desiredUser
(desiredUser) $ 
(desiredUser) $ . custom_profile/my_custom_vars.ksh
```

Is there such an alias that I could use from user1 to accomplish both the `su - <desired_user>` and the sourcing? Once again, I cannot have anything in the .profile / .bashrc / .bash_profile as that would affect other users that also become this batch user.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### With `expect`

Use the following [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

log_user 0
spawn /bin/su - desiredUser
stty -echo
expect "*: "
send_user "Password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send "$expect_out(1,string)\r"
stty echo
send ". custom_profile/my_custom_vars.ksh\r"
interact
```

The lines between `stty -echo` and `stty echo` are responsible for password handling. It's possible to include the password in the script itself. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1343270/432690).

Just after sending the password the script sends the desired command as if you typed it. Then it lets you interact.

The solution is quick and dirty. In particular the script does not wait for a prompt, it sends `. custom_profile/my_custom_vars.ksh` right away. It should work, but if you need to send many commands this way, it may not be a reliable way. Grouping commands in a file and sending just one command to source the file seems better.

---

#### With `--rcfile`

I assume `su - desiredUser` runs `bash`. Bash supports `--rcfile` option:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists. […] The `--rcfile file` option will force Bash to read and execute commands from `file` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files), mind [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/815083/693277))</sup>

The most straightforward way would be to provide `bash --rcfile …` after the `-c` option of `su`, but this option cannot be used to execute interactive programs (see `man 1 su`). To circumvent this, create a custom "shell", a wrapper:

`customshell` (needs to be executable):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/bash --rcfile /full/path/to/your/rc.file "$@"
```

Then invoke `su` like this:

```
su -s /full/path/to/customshell - desiredUser
```

Note this will source `/full/path/to/your/rc.file` *instead* of `~/.bashrc`. To still source `~/.bashrc` you need `. ~/.bashrc` as the first line of the `rc.file`.

Comment: Just an update - `su - desiredUser` actually runs ksh (I know), so the --rcfile didn't seem to be supported. That being said, the `expect` script worked great, although I'll have to do some research on it to make sure I understand all the commands. Thank you!