# How to specify password in ssh command

Tags: command-line, ssh, passwords

From the terminal I type: `ssh user@ip` and then it prompts for a password. 
Is there a way to specify the password in the ssh command itself?

Comment: answer is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780893/use-expect-in-a-bash-script-to-provide-a-password-to-an-ssh-command

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`sshpass`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass), one of two forms:

```
sshpass -ffilename ssh user@ip   # prefer this
sshpass -pPa5sw0rd ssh user@ip   #  avoid this
```

where your password is in the first line of the file `filename` or it is literally `Pa5sw0rd`. Notes:

- In the manual there is no space after `-p` or `-f`, but at least `sshpass` 1.06 in my Debian 10 allows it; your `sshpass` may or may not.
- If your password contains characters your shell will interpret (like `$`, `'` or `;`) then you should quote it properly in the command line (but not in the file).
- **Avoid `-p`.** Use `chmod 600 filename` to make the file private ([root will still be able to access it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117150/108618) though). **Read about security considerations** in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass).

Comment: HI, why do you say to avoid the  -p option with sshpass ?

Comment: @Rohitsharma Because of what the manual states in the *security considerations* section.

Comment: @Rohitsharma - presumably because you are putting your password in plain text into the command.

Comment: Password in command line can be read later in user's bash history.

Comment: Any solution for macOS? `sshpass` isn't part of the default OS, and doesn't seem to be available in Homebrew either.

Comment: @luckman212 `expect(1)`. Example with `su`: [here](https://superuser.com/a/1343270/432690). Adjust it to `ssh`. If you manage to do this, consider posting an answer here. In the answer there is no need to mention my input.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this, is to switch from password authentication to a public/private key pair. This typically needs no reconfiguration at all and is quite easy.

Step 1: If you do not have a key, create one: `ssh-keygen` will do that for you

Step 2: Authorize this key on the remote host: Run `ssh-copy-id user@ip` once, using your password

Step 3: From now on `ssh user@ip` will no longer ask for your password

Comment: Thats correct. But the servers that i am working with are currently having password based authentication. And its really irritating to type password each time they prompt

Comment: from a security perspective this is the correct way to do it. but the OP asked "How to specify password in ssh command".

Comment: Nearly ALL servers allow key authentication **in addition to** password authentication - so you use the password authentication (via `ssh-copy-id`) to enable the key.

Comment: Windows, doesn't have ssh-copy-id, `type $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh {IP-ADDRESS-OR-FQDN} "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"` (from https://chrisjhart.com/Windows-10-ssh-copy-id/)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses [clarkwang/passh](https://github.com/clarkwang/passh). It works on macOS (tested on 13.4.1) as well as Linux, FreeBSD, OpenWRT and some others.

#### Download & compile

Precompiled binaries don't exist at this time, but just a few commands get it installed:

```
git clone https://github.com/clarkwang/passh && cd passh
cc -o passh passh.c
cp passh /usr/local/bin
```

#### Use

```
passh -c1 -C -t10 -T -p hunter2 ssh -t user@host 'echo $HOSTNAME'
```

#### Options explained

- `-c1` only make 1 attempt at password login
- `-C` exit if password login fails
- `-t10` means timeout after 10 seconds
- `-T` exit if timeout occurs
- `-p` specifies the password to input

#### Other options

##### expect

Here's an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1343261/how-to-start-an-interactive-bash-with-su/1343270#1343270) that uses `expect`. I prefer  passh because it doesn't require a HEREDOC or separate script, and works on embedded platforms like OpenWRT that don't always ship with expect.

##### sshpass

`sshpass` was removed from Homebrew, and is a bit [convoluted to install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62623099/617864) on macOS now. The passh author has also documented some details explaining why it's broken at [passh/sshpass-broken.md](https://github.com/clarkwang/passh/blob/master/sshpass-broken.md).

Comment: I did just use `brew install sshpass` this week!

Answer (score 0):

While this might be a ´workarround you can get the job of logging in fast done pretty easily by pasting the password in your clipboard and paste it when prompted. In a batchfile on windows this would look something like this:

```sh
clip <your-password>
ssh <user>@<server>
```

When you run the script just hit `Ctrl + V` and you're in.