# Keeping SSH connections alive from Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, openssh, ssh-multiplexing

I often ssh from Windows to the same Linux server and setup SSH tunnels using this server. The authentication is password-based and this is something that is set up by the company policy, so I cannot change that. Providing same password multiple times is a nightmare.

I've [read about handling that](https://bash-prompt.net/guides/ssh-keep-socket/) by keeping SSH connections alive. The recipe was for Linux-to-Linux connection and required updating `~/.ssh/config` file

```
Host *
  ControlPath    ~/.ssh/%C.sock
  ControlMaster  auto
  ControlPersist 10m
```

On Windows I can define similar file for OpenSSH. However, when I set it up, I started to get

> getsockname failed: Not a socket

I've read [`ControlPath` is not supported on Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/629#issuecomment-503650294). How can I keep SSH connections alive on Windows?

Comment: I found a similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/531443/keeping-ssh-connections-open-on-windows but the answer didn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

> Providing same password multiple times is a nightmare.

<sub>In Linux [`sshpass` could help](https://superuser.com/a/1605240/432690). I don't know if you can use it in Windows. Keep reading.</sub>

Workaround: connect exactly one time to an interactive shell, provide the password one time.

- Port forwardings known in advance may be set up at the time of the connection.
- Port forwardings can be added or removed interactively later. Use the escape character, by default it's the tilde immediately after <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (capital C, so normally in fact <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>), type `-h` <kbd>Enter</kbd>; you should see the overview of commands, they allow adding and removing port forwardings. Notes:

  - See the [manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#ESCAPE_CHARACTERS) for details.
  - You need [`EnableEscapeCommandline yes`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#EnableEscapeCommandline) in your `ssh_config` (`~/.ssh/config`) for this <kbd>~</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to work.
  - The tilde is recognized as the escape character only directly after <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Remember this is <kbd>Enter</kbd> that gets to the remote side anyway.
- Set up `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax`, [so you won't be disconnected when idle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446441/108618).
- If you need more then one terminal, use `tmux` or `screen` on the remote side.