# Pass pw for remote user in bash line when ssh from linux to windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

My goal is to call a .bat file from Linux to Windows, adn pass the remote user pw in the line I use to call this .bat file. I'll explain in detail:

I have to execute a command to run a .bat file in a Windows server as an user of the Windows Server, from a Linux machine. My Linux SO is Centos. The two machine are in the same network so they speak between themselves.

I've decided to try and install an ssh server on windows, and call it via ssh command on Centos. I've installed the ssh server on windows, but it everytime I connect it prompt for manually insert Window's user pw. Is there a way I can parametrize the pw and not be asked to insert it manually?

My ssh code is:

ssh user@SERVERIP
--- bit when i insert the pw
example.bat

What should I do to parametrize the pw from this point on? I didn't see any argument like -p or something in which insert the pw.

Comment: Does "pw" mean "password"? Do you mean the user's password you need to provide in order to log in via SSH? Or does your `.bat` file expect some other password and this is what you mean?

Comment: Perhaps you want this: [*How to specify password in ssh command*](https://superuser.com/q/1605215/432690). Consider key-based authentication.

Comment: Hi
It's exactly what I've been loking for Kamil. Just another simple question: sshpass require glibc 2.15, I've a Centos6 with glibc 2.12. Can I ask you if you know some way to use it? Or maybe another way to pass pw via ssh.

Comment: `expect`, [example here](https://superuser.com/a/1343270/432690) (note the example is for `su`, not for `ssh`). `sshpass` and `expect` are workarounds in this case. In the design of SSH keys are the Right Thing for logging in without password.